# The document type declaration for root element type "plist" must end with '>'

Tags: java, xml

I have such header of xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"/>

<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>frames</key>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I want to use `org.w3c.dom.Document` to read it. When I parse it in this code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
document = builder.parse(path);
```

I get following exception:

```
[Fatal Error] atlas_ID117.plist:2:102: The document type declaration for root element type "plist" must end with '>'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.PlistReader.findFramesList(PlistReader.java:36)
    at main.PlistReader.<init>(PlistReader.java:32)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

As a result `builder.parse` method returns null. But I can't change xml file!

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOCTYPE` isn't an element, and doesn't have the solidus at the end. So remove the `/` before the `>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"/>
Here ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```